# How to embed a expression into string

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have an iframe in my lightning component. The value of the `src` attribute of the iframe is half static and half dynamic e.g.:

```
<iframe src="/apex/customPage?id= \'' + {!v.linkId} + '\' " width="100%"></iframe>
```

But the error I am getting is this:

```
Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: Source
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be  in this way

```
<iframe src="{! '/apex/customPage?id=' + v.linkId}" width="100%"/>
```

the whole attribute value has to be within an expression `{! ...}`

Answer (score 2):

As per the error message, {!'foo' + v.bar} for your expression would be something like this -

```
"{!'/apex/customPage?id=' + v.linkId}"
```

Also I would suggest you to refrain from using hard coded page names. Use the $Page global variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do what the error message is telling you to do:

`/apex/customPage?id= \'' + {!v.linkId} + '\'`

becomes

`{!'/apex/customPage?id=' + v.linkId}`

So the literal becomes part of the expression itself whereas before you had a literal and an expressing in the same attribute, which it doesn't like.